# Link AMD acml in Linux

Tags: linux, linker

I need to link AMD acml library in a C++ project.

I tried to compile it in this way:

```
g++ mainConsole.cpp -L./acml/pgi64_int64/lib -lacml
```

but I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./acml/pgi64_int64/lib/libacml.so when searching for -lacml
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./acml/pgi64_int64/lib/libacml.a when searching for -lacml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lacml
```

What can I do in order to solve?

Comment: Are you building your project as 32- or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the linker was told to use a 64 library when the compilation was done using 32 bits.

Your call to g++ will *both* compile *and* link. It's easier to debug if you split both. For example:

```
g++ -I./acml/pgi64_int64/include mainConsole.cpp -o mainConsole.o
g++ -L./acml/pgi64_int64/lib -lacml mainConsole.o -o mainConsole
```

You can verify the library using *file*. On my system I get:

```
$ file /usr/lib/acml/gfortran/libacml.so
/usr/lib/acml/gfortran/libacml.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

The compiled object should be the same:

```
$ file mainConsole.o 
mainConsole.o: ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

The problem is either 32 bits compilation of your own project, or more probably your use of the "int64" verison of ACML. You can read more on int64 [here](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/knowledge-base/). I suggest you try with the non-int64 version of ACML. For example, instead of downloading acml-5-3-1-pgi-64bit-**int64**.tgz, download acml-5-3-1-pgi-64bit.tgz.